# Asterisk Win32 (SIP) Spawning Thousands of Procceses When Run

Tags: command-line, windows-10, asterisk

***A bit of background:***
Recently I had found [Asterisk for Windows](http://www.asteriskwin32.com/) and decided to see if I could get it set-up on a small home network.  I downloaded the install file from the [download link](http://www.asteriskwin32.com/dwn.php?script=0.66). Next I ran the installer. (Please note that I am running the latest version of Windows 10) The progress bar on the installer goes all the way to the end and reads 'Finalizing Installation'.

At this point, the installer is stuck (not not responding). Gradually my computer began to slow down, CPU usage spiked, and the CPU fan went into overdrive. Curious as to why this was, I *tried* to open up task manager, but to no avail. It would instantly go into a unresponsive state.

Now I was starting to get a bit scared. I opened up the trusty command prompt and did a simple `tasklist` command and found, after waiting for it to complete some 3 minutes later, a hefty amount of asterisk.exe processes running. By hefty amount, I mean thousands!

Thinking that this may be some sort of virus, I start a CMD as administrator and run the `taskkill /im asterisk.exe /f`  command. Normally, this would work great, however it just kept on killing processes and would not stop. In the end, I forcefully shut-down my computer and restarted it.

**TLDR/The Problem:** When running asterisk, the installer or the subsequently installed programs, it continually spawns clones of itself (see screenshot below). 
[image: A few of the thousands of Asterisk.exe proccesses]

I assume that this is not a virus, but a bug within the program either with Windows 10 or some conflict of software/hardware. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling (manually as the uninstaller has the same problem as the installer) however that does not work either.

**Does anyone know what is going on and how to possibly fix this?** If you need any more info or clarification PLEASE ask! :) Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: asteriskwin32 can't be considered stable or ready for production. Even asterisk on linux in vmware work better.

Comment: Do you by any chance know of any other software to act as a phone server for a small local network? I would primarily be using soft-phones.

Comment: yes,asterisk on atom box(from $50 cost used) or asterisk inside vmware will work just ok.Asterisk on $25 router under openwrt or rossberi PI box($25) can work, but require more knowledge to setup

Comment: @arheops I have a router running DDWRT. Would you by any chance have any resources that you go to for using Asterisk on that platform?

Comment: Can say nothing about ddwrt. On openwrt can be installed via opkg,require 8Mb flash or external root.

Comment: @arheops Thank you very much for the information...I will look into it and see if my router meets that requirement.